# UIImage and UILabel disappearing after doing UIRefreshControl

Tags: swift, xcode

UIImages and UILabel are disappearing in some collectionViews after refreshing inside my app.
here is my code. You can see what is wrong in the picture, the left image is before refreshing and there is a discount price label and after refreshing the simulator, it is gone.  getProductLatestData(), getBestSellingData() are the Alamofire get request for API.

```
//For Refresh Controller
//----------------------
var player : AVAudioPlayer

var refreshController : UIRefreshControl = {
    let refreshController = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshController.addTarget(self, action: #selector(updateData), for: .valueChanged)
    return refreshController
}()
//----------------------

//For Update Data when scroll to top
//----------------------------------
@objc func updateData(){
    
    //To play sound when scroll top
    //-----------------------------
    let pathToSound = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Flick", ofType: "wav")
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: pathToSound!)
    
    do {
        
        player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)

        player?.play()

    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    //-----------------------------
    
    //Fetch Latest Products Data
    getProductLatestData(pageNumber: 0, pageSize: 0)
    
    //Fetch BestSelling Products Data
    getBestSellingData(pageNumber: 0, pageSize: 0)
    
    //Fetch Promotion Products Data
    getPromotionProductsData(pageNumber: 0, pageSize: 0)
    
    //Fetch Products By Category
    getProductsByCat(pageNumber: 0, pageSize: 0)
    
    //Fetch Reward Products
    getRewardProducts()
    
    self.refreshController.endRefreshing()
}
 if collectionView == latestItemCV {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "latestItemCell", for: indexPath) as! PromotionItemsCollectionViewCell
        
        if let percent = latestItemData[indexPath.row].promotePercent {
            
            if percent != 0 {
                cell.percentOff.isHidden = false
                cell.percentOff.text = " \(percent) % Off "
                cell.percentOffBackground.isHidden = false
            }
            else{
                cell.percentOff.isHidden = true
                cell.percentOffBackground.isHidden = true
            }
        }
        
        if let name = latestItemData[indexPath.row].name {
            cell.itemsName.text = name
        }
        else{
            cell.itemsName.text = "-"
        }
        
        if let url = latestItemData[indexPath.row].url {
            cell.itemsImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: url), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder"))
        }
//----------------------------------
```

[image: here is the link for image]

Comment: Showing the code on how it set the label that disappear might help. Also `getProductLatestData()`, `getBestSellingData()` etc, are sync methods?

Comment: getProductLatestData(), getBestSellingData() are the alamofire get request for API.

Comment: What's the code that's supposed to show the label?

Comment: @Larme I updated the code mate

Comment: And did `latestItemData[indexPath.row].promotePercent` existed after the refresh? If not, the code that populate `latestItemData` might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @larme I recheck the code here is how I fixed it, I added those disappeared labels isHidden = false also as I did isHidden = true for them.

if let promotionPrice = latestItemData[indexPath.row].promotePrice {

```
            if promotionPrice != 0 {
                
                cell.originalItemsPrice.text = "\(setCommaForPrice(price: Int(promotionPrice))) Ks"
                cell.promotionPercent.isHidden = false
                cell.promotionLine.isHidden = false
            }
            else{
                if let orPrice = latestItemData[indexPath.row].originalPrice {
                    cell.originalItemsPrice.text = "\(setCommaForPrice(price: Int(orPrice))) Ks"
                }
                
                cell.promotionPercent.isHidden = true
                cell.promotionLine.isHidden = true
            }
        }
```